# Laravel 5 Queue assign to multiple workers in beanstalkd

Tags: laravel-5, queue, beanstalkd

I am using laravel 5 and queue driver beanstalkd already installed in application, could someone please suggest what i have to do for achieving parallel processing, i want to run jobs in parallel in a same or different queue. currently it oly process one job at a time which is very time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple workers each watching a number of tubes. Which jobs will be run first depends on any priority when they were put into the system, or simple first-come-first.

It's a very common pattern to start and keep workers (one, or many) running with a tool such as 'SupervisorD'.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Laravel docs:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#supervisor-configuration

Supervisor is that you need. Supervisor will control your workers, if they die, supervisor will restart them again. For parallel processing, check the attribute `numprocs` of Supervisor

From Laravel docs:

> the numprocs directive will instruct Supervisor to run x queue:work processes and monitor all of them, automatically restarting them if they fail.